# How to duplicate a customer address?

Tags: php, magento

When a customer enters an address for the first time than this address serves as billing **and** shipping address. But there is only one entry in the database. So if the customer later decides to alter the shipping address by editing the existing one than the billing address is changed too. To prevent this, I need two separate entries in the database, one for the billing address and one for the shipping address. Therefore,

I wrote an event observer using the event `customer_address_save_after` to check if the entry for the default billing address is identical to the entry of the default shipping address. If so a copy of this address is saved serving as new shipping address. Well, at least this was the idea,

```
public function customerAddressSaveAfter($observer)
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if ($session->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling()  ==
        $session->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping())
    {
        $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();

        $address->unsAddressId()
                ->unsAddressType();           

        Mage::getModel('customer/address')
            ->setData($address->getData())
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
            ->save();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

but running the code seems to result in an infinite loop until the memory is exhausted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're worried about this. Magento has the capability to save multiple addresses already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is infinite recursion because you are saving a 'customer/address' in a 'customer/address' save event.

Set some attribute on your duplicate, and check for it before saving:

```
public function customerAddressSaveAfter($observer)
{
    $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
    if ($address->getIsDuplicate()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 

    if ($session->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling()  ==
        $session->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping())
    {
        $address->unsAddressId()
                ->unsAddressType();           

        Mage::getModel('customer/address')
            ->setData($address->getData())
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
            ->setIsDuplicate(true)
            ->save();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the loop stop when default billing != default shipping?

Comment: @cads: I would be surprised if recursion isn't the reason you're running out of memory. Checking it will take you 5 minutes? :)

Comment: Of course just setting is_default_shipping on some (self-created) address model will not update the default address of the address model in your customer's session. Above fix will at least fix your recursion, but it might also fix the underlying issue.

Comment: I can not test it right now but I am pretty sure your answer is right. I am just trying to understand why the if statement does not stop the process. (edit: just saw your last comment, that explains it :) thank you!)

Comment: @cads: because everytime you enter this observer, the $session result will be the same... saving some address model changes little about that.

Comment: @cads: just saw your edit, which made my last comment irrelevant ;)